# Sortable elements centered using margin: 0 auto snaps to left while sorting

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Jquery UI sortable where the sortable boxes are centered in their container using `margin: 0 auto`.

I use the `axis: 'y'` setting in the sortable so that the boxes can only move vertically.

While sorting, the dragged box moves to the left of the container

Using draggable with `axis: y` does not cause this problem, it seems to be related to sortable widget.

I replicated the bug in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annam/35MC3/28/). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that, jQuery UI applies `position:absolute` upon dragging - Causing the element to be positioned at `top:0`, `left:0` of closest positioned element, or the window.

One option to fix this issue is to use a custom positioned helper for dragging using the [`helper` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper). You can make use of the jquery UI [`position()`](http://jqueryui.com/position/) utility method for easily positioning the helper relative to the original element as follows:

```js
$('#container').sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  helper: function(event, elm) {
    return $(elm).clone().position({
      my: "left",
      at: "left",
      of: elm
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* { /*for stack snippet demo*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="draggable"></div>
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>
```